# servlet text/plain response is always UTF-8

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding, jboss6.x

Java: 1.6
Container: Jboss 6 (Servlet 3.0 Api)

**The problem:**

Every text based response is encoded using UTF-8, not with Charset I want to use. I know UTF-8 rules right now, but this is not the case. I want to use different Charset and I cannot.

**Let's look at this simple code:**

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException{

    response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-2");

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte [] bytes = "Królewna Śnieżka".getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"));
    System.out.println("bytes.length: " + bytes.length);

    outputStream.write(bytes);
}
```

As you see, I want to send text that contains national characters (ó, Ś, ż). With ISO 8859-2 every character is represented by one byte, so the HTTP response should have headers like that:

*Content-Length*: 16
*Content-Type*: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-2

but in response I see:

*Content-Length*: 19
*Content-Type*: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-2

I realized very fast, that national characters are encoded using two bytes, so Content-Lenngth is 19, not 16. I checked message body, and this is true. Text in body is encoded with UTF-8.

**Question:**

Why response is encoded using UTF-8, not explicity used ISO-8859-2?

Comment: Does your response contain 19 bytes? If it does, just read it with your character encoding. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, response contains 19 bytes.The problem is: in HTTP header we see charset=ISO-8859-2, but UTF-8 is used. The response should be encoded with ISO-8859-2, not UTF-8.

Comment: What does your `System.out.println` print?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
byte [] bytes = new String("Królewna Śnieżka".getBytes(),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")).getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2"));
```

---

Setup your html to render chars as ISO-8859-2 by setting

```
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">
</head>
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this worked, but I checked this. Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: Unfortunatelly <head> is not a solution becouse response is text/plain, not text/html. But if this was text/html this would not help since response is actually encoded with UTF-8. The problem is not client side, problem is server side.